# remove application name from URL

Tags: url, jsf, url-rewriting, friendly-url, prettyfaces

my site uses JSF and the url appears to be, http://mysitename.com/wompower6/faces/home.xhtml

I am using prettyfaces, so if I use the following in pretty-config.xml, i can change the name to http://mysitename.com/**wompower6**/home

```
<url-mapping id="home">
    <pattern value="/home" />
    <view-id value="/faces/home.xhtml" />
</url-mapping>
```

my questions are

1. how can i remove the application
   name wompower6 , so that the url
   becomes mysitename.com/home ?
2. in my web.xml, i have
       `<welcome-file>home.xhtml</welcome-file>`,
       but this does not seem to work. When
       i type, mysitename.com, it does not
       get mapped to home.xhtml. any clue
       here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> *how can i remove the application name wompower6 , so that the url becomes mysitename.com/home?*

This is a webapp `<Context>` setting and configuration is dependent on the servletcontainer used. If you're for example using Tomcat, then there are basically 2 options to make your webapp the root webapp.

1. Rename the WAR file to `ROOT.war` and Tomcat will by default deploy it on context root.
2. Set `path` attribute of `<Context>` element in `Webapp/META-INF/context.xml` (or `Tomcat/conf/server.xml`, depending where you'd like to define it) to an empty String. E.g.

   ```xml
   <Context path="" ...>
   ```

Other containers support similar constructs. Consult their documentation for detail. If you're using an IDE like Eclipse, then you can also set it in the *Web Project Settings* property of the project properties (rightclick project and choose *Properties*). Set the *Context root* value to just `/`.

---

> *in my web.xml, i have home.xhtml, but this does not seem to work. When i type, mysitename.com, it does not get mapped to home.xhtml. any clue here?*

I assume that you're talking about the `<welcome-file>` setting. This has to point to a **physically existing** file, not to a virtual URL, such as `/faces/*`. There are basically two ways to overcome this:

1. Provide a **physically existing** `/faces/home.xhtml` file (it can even be left empty).
2. Replace the ugly `/faces/*` URL pattern of the `FacesServlet` mapping in `web.xml` by `*.xhtml` so that it will just kick in on every request for a XHTML file.

   ```xml
   <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
   ```

   This way you don't need to fiddle with `/faces/*` URL patterns.

Comment: As usual, it's again an excellent answer from you. let me do these changes and will update you.

Comment: BalusC, everything seems to be working fine. I checked this in localhost. Thanks for enriching the forum by your knowledge and experience.

Comment: While i tried the same war in mysitename.com, it still expects wompower6. I am using glassfish. Do i have to do any other configuration ?

Comment: got the solution from http://markmail.org/message/uch2dfswtrgsuae2#query:+page:1+mid:6dcmavdydoxyppj3+state:results...... go to glassfish admin console, Configuration -> Virtual Servers -> <server>
    There is a dropdown box with the label :Default Web Module.   Select your
web application as the default one.

Comment: I have the same problem in jetty server.. what modifications will i have to do? help needed...